# For loop into While loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

**Hey I just need this for loop to be made into a while loop been struggling THANKS!**

```
   x = input('Enter a string: ')
   y = 0
   for i in x:
       if i == 'a':
           y += 1
           print(y)
```

Comment: I'm really wondering what kind of language this is.

Comment: Its python sorry the indenting is wrong!

Comment: Then may I suggest you [edit] your question to fix the indentation and add the Python tag.

Comment: Using a `for` here is more idiomatic than a `while` (although better still would be to just `y = x.count('a')`).. why do you want to make this change?

Comment: This type of iteration lends itself much better to a for loop than a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
x = input('Enter a string: ')
y = 0
i = 0
while i < len(x):
  if x[i] == 'a':
      y += 1
      print(y)
  i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so complex! Why don't you use `count` to count number of the word.
The string is combined of characters of a list, so the `count` counts the character.

```
x = input('Enter a string: ')
print x.count('a')
```

If you want to a `while-loop` version as the following:

```
x = input('Enter a string: ')
y = 0
count = 0
while count < len(x):
    if x[count] == 'a':
       y += 1
       print(y)
    count +=1
```

Comment: I know right! However the problem is to make a while loop.

Comment: @jpotty So, you want to do a `while loop` version?